# Dojo class naming

Tags: dojo

I am trying to understand how to name classes by dojo. I think I went through the tutorials but I probably missed something.

Is

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare){
  return declare(null, {
    constructor: function(name){
      this.name = name;
    }
  });
});
```

in Person.js same as

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare){
  return declare("Person", null, {
    constructor: function(name){
      this.name = name;
    }
  });
});
```

in SomeOtherFileName.js?

When do we need to denote file name in the file name vs as an argument to declare? Would the second example create any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class name (first argument of `declare()`) don't need to represent the path to your file. Actually, it is optional. The optional name of the constructor (loosely, a `"class"`) stored in the `"declaredClass"` property in the created prototype. It will be used as a global name for a created constructor.

For example:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare){
  return declare("my.firstWidget", {
    constructor: function(){
      console.log(this.declaredClass)
    }
  });
});
```

This will create a global constructor, `my.firstWidget`, that can be use it like this:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "myApp/myWidget"], function(dom){
  var my = new my.firstWidget(); //note this line
  my.placeAt(dom.byId('someID'));
});
```

But, this is a bad use of it, we have dojo and we must do it the dojo way, this was just for an example.

But, we do can use it in a declarative way, like this:

```
<div data-dojo-type="my.firstWidget"></div>
```

And this is ok.

Actually, the first argument of `declare()` is omitted in new development. This ensures that the global namespace does not become polluted with classes and reduces the chances of name collisions.

The `AMD Module ID (MID)` becomes the commonly referred to class name. This name is implied from the path to the file. For example `myApp/myWidget.js` would make the MID `myApp/myWidget`. And this `MID` is what we can use if we omitted the `class name` and want to use the declarative way

```
<div data-dojo-type="myApp/myWidget"></div>
```

This works too, and this even works if we gave the `class name` to `declare()`

Take a look [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/declare.html) there are a lot of example and info about `declare()` in dojo.

Answer (score 1):

You should place your class in the define statement and use an absolute path to define it. In the function definitions you can then name them anything you like, as long as you keep the order the same. If you reference these in your code then you need to use the value you used for the function name. Be careful to always use the keyword "this" before calling a function. Otherwise it won't be found.

```
define{["dojo/_base/declare",
        "this/is/my/path/Person",
        "this/is/my/path/SomeOtherFileName"],
        function(declare,
                 myPeopleClass,
                 anotherFile) {
return declare("this.is.my.path.CurrentFile", [anotherFile], {

       postCreate : function() {
           var value = this.anotherFunction();
          //some other code
       },

       anotherFunction : function() {
          //more code
          return something;
       }
});
});
```